# Centering a div with its size always same as the image child

Tags: css

I have div1, div2 and an image with the following structure:

```html
<div1>
  <div2>
    <img>
  </div2>
</div1>
```

`div1` already has fixed position and size, I need `div2` always within it and having the same size of the image inside it (the image will be different), image should keeps its ratio and maximized within `div1`'s box. `div2` also needs to be centered in `div1`.

The overall outcome should look similar to `div1` `object-fit:contain` and image inside it (so image will have maximized size with keeping its ratio and centered); the only thing different from my case is I need the `div2`.

My current solution is:

**div1:**

```css
position: absolute;
top, width, height: somevalue;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

**div2:**

```css
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
display: inline-block;
```

**img:**

```css
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%; 
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: auto;`
```

However the image exceeds `div1`.

Comment: Your HTML does not look right. thats not how you add  `<div1>`

Comment: Hi, could you point out how should I fix it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with this css in div2:

```
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
object-fit: contain;
display: contents; // Modified
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does the job which I want it to be. If you don't mind, I have a further question regarding to this: right now the div2 size changes according to the image inside it which is perfect, but is there a way I can add more images positioned absolute to the main image?  I have another images under div2 as well, when I use position absolute, their position always absolute to div1, but I need them to take div2 as their parents. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Freddie Try setting position: relative to div2.

Comment: Hi, there is no difference after adding it to div2. The main image still shows perfectly, but it's sibling image with `position:absolute` still absolute to div1 and not on top of the main image.

Comment: Right now I gave the situation of adding`position: relative`to div2 and remove any `display` config, everything else is doing exact I want except the large image will exceed div1, this confuse me because I have set the`max-height` and `max-width` for the image style.Thanks

Comment: That is because the img take the total width/height setted in div2 and this is not setted. You can set a specific "width" and "height" in div2 and it will work. If you set it as 100% the div will no longer be centered, but you can try centering the images inside or creating a new div inside div2 with the images and configure it.